# use JQuery to add an id for a div to make a dynamic table with JSON and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use Ajax to get the JSON data from a URL to make a dynamic contact table, and use the bootstrap modal to show up a card with specific contact info when user click names on the table. I made every contact modal having their own modal blocks, and want to use the different id to identify and populate the correct data to each modal div, but when I want to add the id attribute to particular div, I find out the id didn't be added in with below code. I can't find where is the problem, so I come here to ask for help.

```
 var modal_elements = $(modalTemplate); 
                    var contactModalid = "myModal" + i.toString();
                    modal_elements.find("#myModal0").attr("id", contactModalid);
                    modal_elements.find("#name").text(contact.name);
                    modalContainer.append(modal_elements);
```

the below is my whole script block in the HTML head for the better understanding of my entire situation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var contactTemplate =
            "<tr><td class=\"contactID\">contact's id goes here</td>" +
            "<td><a data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"contactName\">contact's name goes here</a></td></tr>";

        var modalTemplate = 
        "<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"myModal0\" role=\"dialog\">" + 
        "<div class=\"modal-dialog\">" + 
        "<div class=\"modal-content\">" + 
        "<div class=\"modal-body\" style=\"padding:80px 50px; background-color:DodgerBlue; color: white\">" +
        "<h2 id=\"name\" style=\"text-align: right\"></h2>" + 
        "<p id=\"title\" style=\"text-align: right\">Web Designer</p></div>" + 
        "<div class=\"modal-footer\" style=\"background-color:black; color: white\">" + 
        "<p id=\"phone_email\">222.222.2222 | info@business.com</p><p id=\"address\">1812 Rafe Lane, Jackson, MS 39211</p></div></div></div></div>";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (msg) {
                var container = $("tbody");
                var modalContainer = $("#cardModal");

                for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                    var contact = msg[i];

                    var contact_elements = $(contactTemplate);
                    contact_elements.find(".contactID").text(contact.id);
                    contact_elements.find(".contactName").text(contact.name);
                    contact_elements.find("a").attr("id", i.toString());
                    var herfValue = "#myModal" + i.toString();
                    contact_elements.find("a").attr("href", herfValue);
                    container.append(contact_elements);


                    var modal_elements = $(modalTemplate); 
                    var contactModalid = "myModal" + i.toString();
                    modal_elements.find("#myModal0").attr("id", contactModalid);
                    modal_elements.find("#name").text(contact.name);
                    modalContainer.append(modal_elements);


                };
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: `modal_elements.find("#myModal0")` makes no sense as `$("#myModal0")` would be enough. The `#` indicates that your selecting an id. If its a class you can do `modal_elements.find(".myModal0")`

Comment: all the HTML elements are still in `modal_elements` before we use `append()` to the target `<div>` so I have to use `find()` for `modal_elements` to locate the id, and you can't just use `$("#myModal0")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changing it to

```
modal_elements.attr("id", contactModalid);
```

will fix it.

The element known as `#myModal0` in your template is the element represented by modal_elements, because it's the root element of the ones in the template. Using "find" searches for *children* of the element, but you want to modify the element itself.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, could you explain to me the reason?  There are a few id attributes in the `modal_elements`, but your solution only changes the id in the first `div` tag.

Comment: Also, could you please explain to me why my code doesn't work with more detail? If you look into my code, I use `contact_elements.find("a").attr("id", i.toString());` and `contact_elements.find("a").attr("href", herfValue);` to `find()` the attr and set value after, that works, but why `modal_elements.find("#myModal0").attr("id", contactModalid);`doesn't? Thanks

Comment: because the root element of contact_elements is a `<tr>` - basically the first element in the template string will be the element actually represented by the object. Your jQuery object is not an array, think of it more like a tree structure where the first element in your string becomes the object, and the others can be found as children of it using ".find()". In contact_elements the `<a>` is a child of the `<tr>`, but in modal_elements the `#myModal0` is the first element loaded, so the jQuery object you create _is_ the element #myModal0. Does that make sense?

Comment: My command doesn't modify the other IDs in the template because they are _children_ of the "myModal0" element, whereas running .attr() on the element itself only modifies that element, not its children.

Comment: P.S. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped you solve your problem - thanks :-)

Comment: I kindly understand what your meaning, but do you have any relative reference or resource I can read for a deeper understanding?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but I guess the jQuery docs might be a good place to start: http://api.jquery.com/ There's quite a lot of detail in there about how the selectors and methods work. But the principle isn't really exclusive to jQuery. a HTML document is structured as a hierarchy of elements (just like an XML document). When you use a string of HTML elements to create a document (or part of a document, in this case), it creates that hierarchy, with the first, outermost element as the main element in the document object, and then adds all the others as children, as per your string.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, like **@ADyson** said, when you find element, it finds child element within selected element, so your script should contain

```
modal_elements.attr("id", contactModalid);
```

or
select its previous object

```
modal_elements.find("#myModal0").prevObject[0].id = contactModalid;
```

both will work!!

Comment: thanks for sharing another way to explain where I am wrong. Really helpful.